# How in Yii 2 access AR object as component?

Tags: php, web, yii, yii2

Actually, I want have access to some AR object in anywere.
So I want access to this ojb as yii component.

Like as Yii using this for user: `Yii::$app->user->identity` - User component contains User AR object.

I want store my Page AR in component. So, it's look like something: `Yii::$app->page->page` - Page AR is a propery of Page component. Not very nice :(. This is the only way?

Comment: You can build a component  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-components.html   and   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-application-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config you can set it. Like user is set and adapt it to your requirements.

```
$config = [
    ...
    'components'=>[
        ....
        'user' => [
            'class'=>'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],
...
];
```

Read more in yii2 documentation on this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html)